# How do you get the "Skill Beats Gear" achivement?

Tags: you-must-build-a-boat

In the list of achievements there is this:

> **Skill Beats Gear**
>   Reach Jail without buying anything

Where is jail?

Answer (score 2):

Jail is one of the dungeon names. From memory its the 4th or 5th area you sail to.